# How to add tuple as a value of (key,tuple) map?

Tags: java, dictionary, tuples

I would like to store key,value pair in Map but the value should be a tuple that represents date as a period from: to:. 
What I tried is:

`private Map<PhysicalMedia,(Calendar,Calendar)> mediaOnHold; //book held from: to:`

And also:

`private Map<PhysicalMedia , new Pair<Calendar,Calendar>> mediaOnHold;`

Both of these don't seem to do the job.. What would be the best solution?

Comment: Don't use `new` on the declaration, only when adding your `Pair`s to the map

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a "tuple" in Java. Although you could use `Pair` class (either from `javafx.util` package, or from the [Apache commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library), I'd advice against it, since it usually clutters the code. Just create a specific class for your values:

```java
public class Period {

    private Calendar from;
    private Calendar to;

    // constructor, getters, setters if needed
}
```

And then use it as a value type of the map:

```java
private Map<PhysicalMedia, Period> mediaOnHold;
```

Comment: Thanks I suppose its the best solution !

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. Which language did you use prior to Java?
Anyway

```
private Map<PhysicalMedia , Pair<Calendar, Calendar>> mediaOnHold;
```

But keep in mind `Pair` comes from the `javafx.util` package.